# Why is My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey suddenly returning null when Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey works as expected?

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry, registrykey

I have some old code written in VB.NET that uses [`My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.myservices.registryproxy.localmachine) to open a registry key under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\", but it's returning `null` (`Nothing`) all of the sudden for one just one user.  The assembly is compiled to run on x86.  I replaced the code with [`Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey) and that works fine for that user now.

What is going on?  My theory is that some recent update from Microsoft broke the old code.

Comment: Is that specifically happening to a single user?

Comment: "I replaced the code with Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey and that works fine" - This does not make sense as `My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine` is the same `RegistryKey` instance as `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine`.  Is the OS 32 or 64 bit? Did you test a re-compiled version using the `My.Computer` reference as x86?

Comment: @TnTinMn it's very weird if it's happening to a specific user(s) only. I've ran the same code as the asker has given, that works for me **and it's mandatory to run the app as administrator** to save the registry key and read it.

Comment: Yes single user like I said.  OS is 64 bit (the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ doesn't exist in 32 bit).